# How to press and release a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, click, addeventlistener

I want it to change color when the button is clicked and I implement it in code. But how can I make the button change to the original color when pressed again? So I want the button to turn black when clicked and white again when clicked again.

```
let pushButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.card__itemsize')
pushButtons.forEach( pushButton => 
  {  
  pushButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => 
    { 
    if (e.target === pushButton) 
      { 
      pushButton.classList.add('clickSizeBlack')
      }
    }) 
  })
```

Comment: [did you search in any documentation before posting?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you're trying to achieve is the button to **toggle** switching between two states(pressed and not pressed) which will be represented by the given colors(white and black).

```
let pushButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.card__itemsize');

pushButtons.forEach(pushButton => {
  pushButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target === pushButton) {
      pushButton.classList.toggle('clickSizeBlack');
    }
  });
});
```

The **toggle** method will allow you to add a class if it's not present and remove it if it's already present. In your case, you want to toggle between clickSizeBlack and the original class of the button.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This is really the best solution and everything works great

Answer (score 1):

You need to add else statement as if the `button` has `clickSizeBlack` class, then remove the `clickSizeBlack` class and add `clickSizeWhite` class to that button.
Otherwise always add `clickSizeBlack` class.

```
buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (button.classList.contains('clickSizeWhite')) {
            button.classList.remove('clickSizeWhite');
            button.classList.add('clickSizeBlack');
        } else if (button.classList.contains('clickSizeBlack')) {
            button.classList.remove('clickSizeBlack');
            button.classList.add('clickSizeWhite');
        } else {
            button.classList.add('clickSizeWhite');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works great. Is there a way to make the click smoother?

Comment: You can use `css` transitions or put keyframe animations.